# Copy properties from class A to class B

Tags: c#, .net

Using C#, is there a way to copy properies from Class A that were set ( so if i didnt set some property in Class A I dont want that to get copied over) to class B?

example:

```
class A
{public string Name {get;set;}
public string Age {get;set;}
}

class B
{public string Name {get;set;}
public string Age {get;set;}
}


A a = new A(){name ="bob"}
```

Now i  have `B b = new B(){Age = 30};`
I need to copy A to B that way Name of B gets set and Age stays the same. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that a property whose value is null does not get copied? What if it's an integer property? How would you distinguish between the default value 0 and a property that was set to zero?

Comment: Yeah that's the tricky part, I was wondering if we are able to just copy whatever we explecitly set.

Comment: What happens if the types aren't compatible? For example A has a property B doesn't. Or A has an property that isn't assignment compatible with the same named property in B.

Comment: I think questioner means copying property values from one object to another object of same class.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much same class, and have many classes that could need stuff scopied over. and in each class i also could have complex types.

Answer (score 3):

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like:

```
if (b.Name == null) b.Name = a.Name;
if (b.Age == null) b.Age = a.Age;
```

But this won't work for value types (like `Int32`). For those, if you control the definition of the type, you could use `Nullable<T>`.